# vscode Quick open in a specific folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I have A LOT of files that have the same filename. Is there any way to quick open a file in a specific folder?

Comment: Have you tried typing the folder name and the file name?

Comment: @Wosi yes. It didn't work though.

Comment: If you type `sys log makefile` then you should see only one entry. If it doesn't work then please show us your settings.json.

Comment: @Wosi Oh, I typed like `makefile sys log`. Now I typed `sys log makefile` and it works :) Thank you.